# Externally turn ON/OFF permissions in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, android-permissions

In my flutter application, I am customizing a few options by automatically replacing a `.properties` file when building, to fit the needs of multiple clients.

Now a new client needs a version of the app that has no location tracking, so I need to turn on/off the location permission to this client only. Is there any way to achieve this with a `.properties` file or something else?

Answer (score 1):

This can ordinary be done with [product flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors) and the [`tools:node="remove"`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#node_markers) marker.

Of course that product flavor *must not* access the `FusedLocationProvider`, as well.